What sould i do Datepicker has an error i cant solve it
import { useField } from "formik";
import { Form, Label} from "semantic-ui-react";
import DatePicker, {DatePickerProps} from 'react-datepicker';

export default function MyDateInput(props: Partial<DatePickerProps>) {
    const [field, meta, helpers ] = useField(props.name!);
    return (
        <Form.Field error={meta.touched && !!meta.error} >
            <DatePicker
                {...field}
                {...props} 
                selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}
                onChange={value => helpers.setValue(value)}
            />
            {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
                <Label basic color='red'>{meta.error}</Label>
            ) : null}
        </Form.Field>
    )
}

on line 9 datepicker is with a red line underneath it making it an error. The type of error i get is this : Types of property 'showMonthYearDropdown' are incompatible.
Type 'true | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
What should i do to fix it.

Error cause

It is said that DatePicker only allows undefined types. This results in a type mismatch

Error resolution

If you want to keep showMonthYearDropdown, you can explicitly set it to undefined when necessary, like this:

    <DatePicker
       {...field}
       {...props}
       showMonthYearDropdown={props.showMonthYearDropdown ?? undefined}
    />

